# Code review проекта на php

Tags: php, solid

Пробую писать свой первый солид проект. Хочу узнать, насколько мой код соответствует принципам солид и где я ошибаюсь. Файл `index.php` :

```
<?php

use broker\Receive;
use broker\Message;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $class . '.php');

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
});

$action = new Message();
$receive = new Receive($action);
$receive->listen();
```

Класс `Receive` который слушает события:

```
namespace broker;

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use interfaces\SaveInterface;

class Receive
{
    public $save;

    public function __construct(SaveInterface $save)
    {
        $this->save = $save;
    }

    public function listen()
    {
        ...
        $this->save->save_message($msg);
        ...
    }
}
```

Класс `Message`, который работает с сообщением

```
namespace broker;

use interfaces\SaveInterface;

class Message implements SaveInterface
{
    public function save_message($message)
    {
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

Интерфейс `SaveInterface`

```
<?
namespace interfaces;

interface SaveInterface
{
    public function save_message($message);
}
```

Comment: Слишком мало кода для оценки. Да, вы работаете с абстракцией, а не с классом,  выполнили прицип D. Всё.

Comment: И зачем юзать `spl_autoload_register` если есть композер? Композер в этот функционал тоже умеет.

Comment: @Pavel, Это касается вот этой строчки `public function __construct(SaveInterface $save)`? Для меня она почему-то самая непонятная. Т.е. когда мы создаем объект $action и передаем его конструктору класса Receive `$action = new Message(); $receive = new Receive($action);` , то в конструкторе мы же можем сделать просто так `public function __construct($save)` и результат будет такой же. Тогда почему делать именно `public function __construct(SaveInterface $save)`?

Comment: @Pavel, почему делать зависимость именно от `SaveInterface`? Потому что, в следующий раз мы может конструктору передавать объект другого класса, который зависит от того же интерфейса? Например, `$action = new Mail();
$receive = new Receive($action);`. P.S. А первый принцип не соблюден (Класс который получает сообщение и класс который сохраняет у них разные ответственности)?

Comment: @r.mcreal с интерфейсом вы сможете передавать в конструктор Receive не только Message, но и любой другой SaveInterface. Если вы привяжетесь жестко к классу Message, то не сможете расширить свой функционал и передать туда другой класс. Если же вообще не будете использовать тайпхинтинг - то сможете передавать все что угодно, но тогда не будет уверенности какие методы надо реализовать, чтобы Receive работал корректно.

Comment: @Pavel, так я и думал спасибо! Еще есть такой вопрос, в symfony есть возможность  принимать в методе зависимости заранее не передавая их. Т.е. если привести это на мой пример выглядит это вот так `$receive = new Receive();` и сама зависимость `public function __construct(SaveInterface $save)`. Мы каким-то образом получаем зависимость не передавая ее

Comment: @r.mcreal читайте про  "Сервис контейнер"

Comment: @Pavel, Окей, спасибо